# I need to print the entire content of a vaadin-vertical-layout inside a vaadin-dialog-overlay

Tags: html, css, vaadin

I am using jmix framework (that uses Vaadin indirectly).
I need to print the entire content of a vaadin-vertical-layout.
I have added this css that helps:

```
.vertical-layout-class {

   display: visible !important;
   overflow: visible !important;
   height: auto !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   left: 0px !important;
   top: 0px !important;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: white; /* You can set the background color or image as desired */
   z-index: 9999; /* Ensure the div is on top of other elements */
   page-break-before: always;
 }
```

But it prints only one page because it renders the vaadin-scroller with its scrollbars.
I need to print the entire contents that spans several pages.
In a simpler page without vaadin-scroller using page-break and overflow I was able to.
The vaadin-scroller is the show stopper for me. I am not able to find a css+selector combo that works.

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: Not a direct solution to this but have you tried creating a print view? I.e. take the layout out of the dialog and put it on the screen by itself without any scrollers just for printing

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to modfiy the page I can use only css